# Difference between }); and )};

Tags: jquery, tags

I have been practising with jQuery a couple of days, and I've found something that I didn't seem to understand, therefore this question on Stack-overflow

Whenever you want to **close a tag** in jQuery, is there a difference between `});` and `)};` as I've seen both closing tags used.

Comment: `});` use for `({` , `)};` use for `{(` its a matter of starting and ending

Answer (score 2):

> Whenever you want to close a tag in jQuery, is there a difference
>   between }); and )};

In jQuery:

- a **call** begins with `(` and ends with `)`.
- a **function** begins with `{` and ends with `}`.

quite often, in jQuery, you'll see a function nested inside a call.

**eg.**

```
$('[QUERY]').[EVENT](function(){

    [... CODE HERE ...]

});
```

If you separate this out, you'll see you have a function:

```
function(){[... CODE HERE ...]}
```

inside a call:

```
.[EVENT]( [...] );
```

So, in this instance, when you see `});` the curly brace and the parenthesis are completely separate from each other:

- The `}` closes the **function**
- The `)` closes the **call**

Answer (score 0):

For example,

$(document).ready(function(){
});

Let's elaborate this only.

```
function(){
```

this part has opened before

```
$(document).ready(
```

, so need to close

`function(){ //...}`

And then need to close document braces as

```
$(document).ready( //.... )
```

Here // ... of `$(document).ready` will be replaced by `function(){ //...}`.

So it will form

```
$(document).ready(function(){
// ...
});
```

This is general methodologies we all do follow in most of the technologies.

This concept will be common all over. like in mathematics also.

```
answer = {[a+b]+[(c*d)+(d*e)]}
```

From small chunks to big chunk we close the braces. Same concept in jquery also.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how these are opened.

- If it opens with `({`, it closes with `})`
- If it opens with `{(`, it closes with `)}`

Example:

```
button.click(function() {
  // Code
});
```

This was opened by `click`**(**`function()`**{** so it closes with `})`.